# Best way to add amp and sub to car

Tags: electrical, chevrolet, audio, cavalier

I just got my first car, a Chevy Cavalier 2000 base, and I would like to put in a new radio, a decent amp and sub to drive the speakers and sub. I am right now looking at this [radio](http://www.crutchfield.com/p_113KMBT315/Kenwood-KMM-BT315U.html?tp=5684). I would like to have a LOT of power and bass.

Do I need a 6 channel amp because the radio is 6 channel?

Can I connect the stock speakers to the amp, or can I connect them to the radio directly?

How do hook everything up, can I find a wiring diagram somewhere for what I am trying to do?

I am new and have absolutely no idea and am looking for guidance for how to have an awesome sound system.

Comment: You're asking a shopping question, we don't give shopping advice as the information changes.  I'll edit it out for you.  As well, your question(s) are WAY too broad.  Trying and focus on different pieces.  Amp question, speaker question, power question, where can I find a diagram question, wattage question, etc.   It will get closed as too broad if you don't edit it down.

Comment: I've removed the shopping part of the question - but I agree with @DucatiKiller that it's still too broad...

Answer (score 4):

The head unit will supply enough power to the stock speakers. You will not need to amplify the signal. Doing so will likely blow the speakers. If you replace your stock speakers with higher wattage speakers, you may need an amp with the channels to power these.

A one or two channel (bridgeable) amp is sufficient for the subwoofer(s).

When I had a system, 2-500w 12 inch subs with a 1000w single-channel amp, and 4-100w 6x9s with a 400w 4-channel amp was much more than enough for me. But, I guess this can be subjective.

I used a cheaper line of Rockford Fosgates for the 6x9s. They sounded a little tinny, but were loud. I used 2 Jenson 12s in a bandpass box, also very loud (turning system up was like getting a message), but not as deep as a 15" could have been.

If you're just going to add the head-unit, subwoofer(s), and leave the stock speakers in, you need a wiring harness to hook up the head-unit to the stock speaker wires. The wiring harness should come with a diagram. Then you will want to run one or two RCA cables from head unit to the trunk into the amp. Then run a large amp power cable from the battery to the trunk somehow. Depending on the car, running the cables to the trunk can be a little complicated, with plenty of opportunities to mess stuff up, so you may want to have a professional installation from a place that has a good reputation.

Comment: The statement about the head unit driving highs is simply incorrect. Speakers are destroyed by being overdriven, which often happens more easily when *underpowered*. An external amplifier on the highs almost always provides a cleaner signal to the speaker, and is therefore beneficial.